# Format a command in powershell including a comma, can't find the right way to escape

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping, powershell-2.0

I have a command that I need to run in a Powershell script, the command is :

```
".\pacli DELETEUSER DESTUSER='"dilip.v@astramwp`,com"' sessionid=333" | invoke-expression
```

The comma (`,`) in here `:dilip.v@astramwp,com` is not a mistake, and that's what is giving me the hard time.

I tried to escape the comma with `` ` `` (backtick) - but its not working.

How do I escape this ?

**I get the error message :**

```
parse error, expecting `';''
```

**and in some variations :**

```
Unexpected token 'dilip.v@astramwp`,com"`' sessionid=333"' in expression or statement.
At C:\CyberArk\Harel CyberArk WebService\deleteUser.ps1:6 char:70
+ ".\pacli DELETEUSER DESTUSER='"dilip.v@astramwp`,com"' sessionid=333" <<<<  | invoke-expression
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (dilip.v@astramwp`,com"`' sessionid=333":String) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

The command works when I use `cmd.exe` and just wrap it with `""`.

Comment: I'd say add `&` to the beginning of the string, this command unescapes parameter list better than plain call to `Invoke-Expression`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> ".\pacli DELETEUSER DESTUSER='"dilip.v@astramwp`,com"' sessionid=333"
> ```

You have double quotes in single quotes in double quotes, so the inner double quotes will terminate the string, so this will be parsed as three values:

```
".\pacli DELETEUSER DESTUSER='"
dilip.v@astramwp`,com
"' sessionid=333"
```

The answer is to escape, with a back tick (`` ` ``), the inner double quotes:

```
".\pacli DELETEUSER DESTUSER='`"dilip.v@astramwp`,com`"' sessionid=333"
```

and thus those double quotes will be passed through to the command.

(As noted in the comments to the question, you'll also need to prefix the string with `&` to get PSH to treat it as a command.)